# OctoPack vs nuget.exe - Which one is faster?

Tags: nuget-package, octopus-deploy

I'm currently trying to speed up our Team City builds.

After a successful msbuild step, we package up our solution using nuget.exe and then publish to a nuget feed in order to allow Octopus Deploy to do it's thing.

I'm at the stage now where the nuget package step takes ~4 minutes (we have a large amount of assets) and the nuget publish step takes ~30 seconds. This takes up about 75% of our overall build time, so any time I can shave off this would be good progress.

I was wondering if anyone has any experience with both OctoPack and nuget.exe, and are in a position to tell me if either of the two methods are quicker than the other? No hard numbers needed, just anecdotal evidence is enough.

Comment: Octopack uses nuget to create Nuget packages for a very specific scenario - deployment with Octopus Deploy. You can't use nuget in place of Octopack. If you rephrase the question "How to spead up my Teamcity build", the answer is "Add Octopack to your project and pass the /p:RunOctopack parameter to msbuild, so you don't need the extra step of individually packaging every deployment target"

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You can create Octopus Deploy packages using only nuget.exe if you like. More info here http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Packaging+applications.

Comment: @MEMark been there, don't want to go again. No reason to go the manual way when an automated way is available. The page you posted *doesn't* explain what's needed to create a proper Octopus package using Nuget. You need to remove files that aren't used by Octopus, add scripts, transformations etc

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My intention was not to explain how it's done, but rather contrast your statement that Nuget can't be used in place of Octopack, which I would say it very much can (and Octopus themselves seem to agree).

Answer (score 2):

The Octopack uses NuGet.exe so you can't really contrast them. You can view the [OctoPack source code on GitHub](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctoPack) to see how it works. I would point out that using a different version of NuGet.exe *might* make a difference. I have no evidence to support this but it's a shot in the dark.

Within the OctoPack, you can pass a parameter (NuGetExePath) to specify the specifc NuGet.exe you want to use. See this [targets file within the Octopack](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctoPack/blob/master/source/tools/OctoPack.targets) for more information on parameters you can pass to OctoPack.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used nuget.exe but I do use Octopack and what I can tell you is that it packages up the three projects in our solution in 3 secs, 7 secs and 12 secs respectively.

The publish artifacts stage for each package takes between two and four seconds. Obviously if you have a large number of assets there is more to consider but hopefully that will give you a flavour of time spent per package.

Also, you can be up and running with Octopack in moments as it is just a case of installing the [Octopack Nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/OctoPack/) in your solution and check the Run Octopack box in your build step in Team City:

[image]

Comment: Since asking this, I've had someone tell me that they think Octopack uses nuget.exe under the hood, so won't be any quicker. I'll give Octopack a go and see what I get

Comment: Octopack is just a convenient wrapper for nuget.exe - see, for example, RunNuGet() method in [the sources](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctoPack/blob/master/source/OctoPack.Tasks/CreateOctoPackPackage.cs).